# Outer measure and Measurable set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, self-learning, outer-measure

Let $ Ω =  \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} = { (i,j) : i,j ∈ \mathbb{N}}$,

and for any set  $ A \subset Ω $ , let $μ(Α)$ be the number of distinct first coordinates among the points in $A$, i.e,

$μ(Α)$ = #( { $i:$ there exists $j ∈  \mathbb{N}$ such that $(i,j) ∈ A $} , $A \subset Ω$.

Note that $μ$  can be written as

$ μ(Α) =$ # $( π_1 (Α))$  $A \subset Ω$ ,

Where # is counting measure on  $(  \mathbb{N} , 2^ \mathbb{N} )$
  and $π_1  : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}  - > \mathbb{N}$   is the projection mapping each point in $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} $ onto it's first coordinate ,

i.e  $π_1 ( ( i,j)) = i , (i,j) ∈ \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$.

**Question** I want to show the below:

**i) $μ$ is an outer measure**

**ii) Characterize the class of μ-measurable sets.**

and **is μ a measure on $2^Ω$?**

Comment: For questions, i) ii) I tried to use the two  theorems from the book of Billingsley       ( page 165)                                      
      https://www.colorado.edu/amath/sites/default/files/attached-files/billingsley.pdf

Comment: In the above exercise for example , if A = { (1,1), (1,3), (2,2), (3,2), (3,4), (3,5)} , then $μ(Α)$ = 3.,  Smillarly , $μ((1) \times  \mathbb{N})$ = 1  while  $μ(\mathbb{N} \times   (1))$ =  $\infty$

Comment: Since I am new I would really appreciate if you could explain your solution.